# Nested SQL Query and Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure it's simple, but I'm having a hard time coming up with the right update/select statement.

I have a table called POSTS.  The table has POSTID which is PK.  It has PARENTID which is currently all NULL.  It also has GROUPID which has a legacy numerical value that groups POSTS together.

An example of the GROUPID, if I have three posts that make up a single thread, they would all have the same value in GROUPID.

What I'm trying to do is to loop through each record, make a note of the POSTID and GROUPID, select all other records that have the same GROUPID and update their PARENTID with the POSTID I noted from the first search.

```
| POSTID | PARENTID | GROUPID |
| 109    | NULL     | 20      |
| 110    | NULL     | 20      |
| 111    | NULL     | 20      |
| 112    | NULL     | 21      |
| 113    | NULL     | 21      |
```

I want to make it as follows:

```
| POSTID | PARENTID | GROUPID |
| 109    | NULL     | 20      |
| 110    | 109      | 20      |
| 111    | 109      | 20      |
| 112    | NULL     | 21      |
| 113    | 112      | 21      |
```

I hope it makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to understand, you're seeking the min(POSTID) where the GROUPID is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you can `join` the table back to itself using the `min` aggregate.  Then you can use case to determine if the min post id is the parent or not.

Here is one way to do this:

```
select t.postid,
  case when postid <> minpostid then minpostid end parentid,
  t.groupid
from yourtable t
  join (select groupid, min(postid) minpostid 
    from yourtable t2 
    group by groupid) t2 on t.groupid = t2.groupid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b990b/3)

---

If you want to `update` the data in your table, you can use the same query with a `join`:

```
update yourtable t
  join (select groupid, min(postid) minpostid 
    from yourtable t2 
    group by groupid) t2 on t.groupid = t2.groupid
set t.parentid = case when postid <> minpostid then minpostid end;
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38851/1)

Comment: Are you like ... Some sort of MySQL god ... I was staring at that for ages Lol ... And come up with nothing like that Lol